# Are there any alternative endings in Hotline Miami 2?

Tags: hotline-miami-2

In Hotline Miami 1 there were two different endings in the Motorcycle Guy storyline.  I'm wondering if Hotline Miami 2 has any secret or alternate endings similar to the one in 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far I've found 1 alternate ending:

Jake:

> On Jake's last mission, Withdrawl, if you clear both floors without dying, you'll be treated to an additional cutscene involving 50B. In this cutscene Jake goes along with the leader of 50 blessings to a safe house, only to be killed by him.
>
>  Canonically, he is incapacitated in the final mission of his, then dragged to another room and shot in the head (leading to you finding his mask in Hotline Miami 1)

Evan:

- On the 13th scene, Subway, in the intro, if you listen to the answering machine before leaving for the subway, you will be able to experience an interesting cutscene after completing the level.

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about scene 14. There are three floors, it is only the last floor you can die on. If you die there, you have to restart from the beginning to continue.

Comment: Ah, and if you survive you get the bonus scene Abyss unlocked.